# How to make an array loaded from netCDF (.nc) writeable?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, io, netcdf

I am loading a few variables from a netcdf (`.nc`) file using python `scipy.io.netcdf` module. In the file that I am loading them from, missing data have a filler value of 99999, which I want to change to `np.nan` from numpy.

Once I have imported a variable and assigned it to a numpy array however, I can't clean up the 99999 filler values because I get:

```
    RuntimeError: array is not writeable
```

I have attempted to change the attribute of the array `writeable` to `True` but that returns:

```
    ValueError: cannot set WRITEABLE flag to True of this array
```

So I am at a loss. A simplified version of my code and a couple example outputs are below. Does anyone have any suggestions here? Originally I was using `netCDF4` rather than `scipy.io.netcdf` and in that case I would set `nc.set_auto_mask(False)` however I haven't seen an analogous property in `scipy.io` so I have just left that out.

Sample code:

```
    import scipy.io as sio
    import numpy as np

    nc = sio.netcdf.netcdf_file('filename.nc','r') # open file
    arr = nc.variables['PARAMETER'][:] # load into np array
    output_arr = cleanarr(arr) # replace filler 99999 vals with np.nan
    nc.close()
```

Worth noting is it doesn't seem to matter if I do `nc.close()` before or after `cleanarr(arr)`

Sample outputs:

```
    type(arr)
        <type 'numpy.ndarray'>

    arr.flags
          C_CONTIGUOUS : True
          F_CONTIGUOUS : False
          OWNDATA : False
          WRITEABLE : False
          ALIGNED : True
          UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.io.netcdf.netcdf_file.html

```
NetCDF files, when opened read-only, return arrays that refer directly to memory-mapped data on disk:

>>>
>>> data = time[:]
>>> data.base.base
<mmap.mmap object at 0x7fe753763180>
If the data is to be processed after the file is closed, it needs to be copied to main memory:

>>>
>>> data = time[:].copy()
>>> f.close()
>>> data.mean()
```

I think this has also been addressed in earlier SO questions, though I haven't taken the time to look those up.

Comment: This worked perfectly - and I better understand what is happening in your solution than the one I posted below. Thanks.

Comment: The `netCDF4` module has replaced the `scipy.io.netcdf` module.  I recommend switching over to it, more details can be found here: https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf4-python

Comment: But does `netCDF4` handle this 'read-only' issue any differently?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by using `np.require` (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.require.html) to change the flags rather than the original method I was using. Code now looks like:

```
    import scipy.io as sio
    import numpy as np

    nc = sio.netcdf.netcdf_file('filename.nc','r') # open file
    arr = nc.variables['PARAMETER'][:] # load into np array
    arr = np.require(arr,dtype='f4',requirements=['O','W'])
    output_arr = cleanarr(arr) # replace filler 99999 vals with np.nan
    nc.close()
```

This seems to do the job but if anyone can comment on the validity of my answer in terms of whether should or shouldn't be done generally (I feel like I am forcing something here, and I have never used `np.require` before) I would appreciate it.

Comment: Does a plain `.copy` also work?  `require` is a `copy` with some flags parameters.